# Setting Up Environments with SaltStack

Tags: git, salt-stack

**How do I make minions use a particular SaltStack environment?**

The [GitFS backend tutorial](http://docs.saltstack.com/topics/tutorials/gitfs.html?highlight=gitfs#branches-environments-and-top-sls-files) states that *branches will be mapped to environments using the branch name as identifier*. How do I expose these environments to my minions?

As an example, let's say [I have a branch](https://github.com/rgbkrk/salt-nbviewer) named "pippy". I'd like to deploy that branch to particular minions.

It seems like I can set the environment via the minion's configuration file. Are there other ways that can be done from the salt master?

Comment: I found myself here trying to figure out how to use environments to version and promote state configs up through dev/test/prod. I'm not sure this is the use case for this, since I've run in to some issues. I posted more at length about it in the mailing list: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/salt-users/4P9YpaFdRTQ

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The key here is that the `top.sls` file is cross-environment.  Before we jump into that, it's important to note that while most branches will be mapped to environments of the same name, the exception is that the `master` branch will be mapped to the `base` environment.

Anyway, on to `top.sls`.  In `top.sls` you define your environments, which minions are members of that environment, and which statefiles will be run from that environment for a `state.highstate`.

```
base:
  '*':
    - basestate
dev:
  'webserver*dev*':
    - webserver
  'db*dev*':
    - db
qa:
  'webserver*qa*':
    - webserver
  'db*qa*':
    - db
pippy:
  'webserver*pippy*':
    - webserver
  'db*pippy*':
    - db
```

So, all minions will run the `basestate.sls` file from the `base` environment.  Only the targeted minions will run the states from each of the other environments.

There is much more information [in the topfile documentation](http://docs.saltstack.com/ref/states/top.html).

Defining the environment option in the minion config just isolates a minion to a specific environment.  It's much more flexible and powerful to define your environments from your topfile.

Comment: I see now. I kept skipping the topfile section thinking that my `top.sls` would be in the git repo, and such wasn't the right option for pushing across branches (and changes across top.sls).

Comment: What happens if the top.sls file differs between branches?

Comment: There's a note about halfway down in that documentation, but basically the top file from each environment will be combined into a single top data structure. The base environment will win in conflicts. Generally, it's easiest to just keep the top file in the base (master) environment.

Comment: @Kyle: 

The base environment's top file is processed first. Any environment
which is defined in the base top.sls as well as another environment's
top file, will use the instance of the environment configured in base
and ignore all other instances. In other words, the base top file is
authoritative when defining environments.

source: http://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/top.html 22.26.18.3, section 1)

Comment: "Defining the environment option in the minion config..." << Was looking EVERYWHERE for this bit of info. Salt docs thoroughly cover environment setups, but never mentions how you actually PICK one of them. The minion file has an `environment` variable; set that to match the proper environment and you're good to go. I know, I shoulda read the minion commentary closer. ;)